# npm commands fail on azure pipelines because of husky install in prepare script

Tags: npm, azure-pipelines-yaml, husky

In our package.json file we have a script `"prepare": "husky install"`. This script runs after the `npm install` and before the `npm publish`. It fails in the azure pipeline because it says that the command husky is not found. We don't need the prepare script to run on the build server only in our local development environments.  For the install, we changed

```
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: "npm publish"
  inputs:
    command: 'ci'
```

to be

```
- script: "npm ci --no-audit --progress=false --omit=dev --ignore-scripts"
  displayName: "npm install"
```

and that stopped it from running `husky install` after the install. But I am not sure how to get the publish command to stop from running husky install. The publish command looks like this:

```
  displayName: "npm publish"
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    workingDir: 'dist'
    publishRegistry: 'useFeed'
    publishFeed: 'xxxxxxs-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx'
```

I have also tried adding the following to the pipeline:

```
- script: "npm config set ignore-scripts true"
  displayName: "npm ignore scripts"
```

Comment: did you get any solutions?